# Calculate percentage cumsum in monthly data in Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame with daily sales data for a number of stores over several years in the following format:

```
            store  sales    cumulative_monthly_sales    
date
2005-07-01  1       2       2
2005-07-01  2       3       3
2005-07-31  1       8       10
2005-08-01  1       5       5
2005-08-30  1       5       10
...
```

I would like to calculate a new column `sales_progress_pct` which is the percentage of monthly sales achieved by a particular date in each store. In this example:

```
            store  sales    cumulative_monthly_sales    sales_progress_pct
date
2005-07-01  1       3       3                           1.00
2005-07-01  2       2       2                           0.20
2005-07-31  2       8       10                          1.00
2005-08-01  1       5       5                           0.50
2005-08-30  1       5       10                          1.00
...
```

Comment: Example output how it is 1 for row 3

Comment: On 2005-07-31 the cumulative monthly sales in store 2 for the month of July are 10. Since that is the last day of the month and there are no more sales in July, the sales progress percentage is 100% (presented as 1.00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case do with `transform`

```
s=df['cumulative_monthly_sales'].groupby([df.index.strftime('%Y-%m'), df.store]).transfomr('max')
df['sales_progress_pct']=df['cumulative_monthly_sales']/s
```